# Bookmark identical lines in other files

Tags: notepad++, text-files

I need to delete same lines that are in two files. So, I want to find lines that are from file1 and delete in file2. My first thought was to bookmark all the lines from file1.

How can I bookmark those lines in the file2 so than I can delete bookmarked lines?

**file-1.txt:**

```
# level04 <- c(-43, -30, -40, -67, -69, -75, -35, -23, -113, -108, -45, -25)
# level05 <- c(-12, 2, -13, -47, -31, -30, -30, -24, -51, -67, -20, -20, -30)
# level06 <- c(-185, -126, -127, -171, -135, -223, 13, -158, -221, -260, -155)
# level07 <- c(-127, -94, -95, -82, -69, -85, -63, -105, -117, -148, -111, -91)
# level08 <- c(-118, -75, -88, -76, -86, -169, -76, -87, -114, -122, -88)
# level09 <- c(197, 121, 148, 138, 92, 238, 219, 129, 106, 0, 120, 67, 142)
# level10 <- c(174, 154, 117, 166, 120, 112, 60, 183, 285, 466, 183, 222)
```

**file-2.txt:**

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# level1004 <- c(-43, -30, -40, -67, -69, -75, -35, -23, -113, -108, -45, -25)
# level05 <- c(-12, 2, -13, -47, -31, -30, -30, -24, -51, -67, -20, -20, -30)
# level1006 <- c(-185, -126, -127, -171, -135, -223, 13, -158, -221, -260, -155)
# level07 <- c(-127, -94, -95, -82, -69, -85, -63, -105, -117, -148, -111, -91)
# level1008 <- c(-118, -75, -88, -76, -86, -169, -76, -87, -114, -122, -88)
# level09 <- c(197, 121, 148, 138, 92, 238, 219, 129, 106, 0, 120, 67, 142)
# level1010 <- c(174, 154, 117, 166, 120, 112, 60, 183, 285, 466, 183, 222)
#
# line 1
#
# line 2
```

Answer (score 3):

First you need to make sure you have a copy of the files.

So, as I added to your question above let’s suppose that you have a `file-2.txt` with some of records and a smaller `file-1.txt`. This `file-1.txt` may contain some records identical to those in `file-2.txt`.

You need to bookmark all the record of `file-2.txt` that have a same record in `file-1.txt`.

So, follow the steps below (don't be scared, it's easy once you've done it.):

- First open file `file-1.txt` in Notepad++
- Select all the contents of `file-1.txt` ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> )
- Save to clipboard ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> )
- Open your second file `file-2.txt`
- At the end of `file-2.txt` add a new line with many e.g. colons :::::: (or %, @, etc.) not present in both files, which will be like a delimiter between the two files!
- Append the contents of the clipboard at the end of `file-2.txt` after the line :::::: ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> )
- Go back to very beginning of the present `file-2.txt`( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Pos1</kbd>  )
- Open the Find dialog ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> )
- Select the Mark tab
- Check the Bookmark line option
- Select the Regular expression search mode
- Find what: `(?-s)^(.+\R)(?=(?s).*:::::::.*?\1)`
- Click on the Mark All button

All the lines, of `file-2.txt` with an identical line located after the line `::::::`, ( `file-1.txt` ) are bookmarked.

Move to line `::::::` and delete all the appended lines of `file-1.txt` to the end of the file. Finally, save the new state of `file-2.txt`, with all the bookmarks or delete these line for your needs.

[image]

Comment: Yes this works but why it works only in small files doesnt work on large files over 1gb

Comment: @Stew - for further information please see [How to open a big file in Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/286106/how-to-open-a-big-file-in-notepad). BTW - you didn't ask for 1GB text files.